# CucumberJS and Allure-CucumberJS: Result File Not Generated

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, allure, cucumberjs

I have done my due diligence searching for an answer to this, but I cannot figure it out.

I am using "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.0.0" to run my tests.

- Example script in package.json:  "debug": "PWDEBUG=console cucumber-js --tags @focus --exit --profile"

I am using Allure-CucumberJS to try to generate a report.

- "allure-commandline": "^2.24.1"
- "allure-cucumberjs": "^2.9.2"
- "allure-js-commons": "^2.9.2"

In my cucumber.js I have the following:

```
module.exports = {
  default: {
    ...common,
    format: 'src/reporter.js',
    paths: [
      'src/reporter.js'
    ]
  }
```

My reporter.js contains the following:

```
import { AllureRuntime, CucumberJSAllureFormatter } from "allure-cucumberjs";

export default class Reporter extends CucumberJSAllureFormatter {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options, new AllureRuntime({ resultsDir: "./allure-results" }), {});
  }
}
```

To generate and open the Allure report I am running the following:

- allure generate allure-results --clean
- allure open ./allure-report/

The only file being generated in allure-results is the report.json, which contains the correct and updated info about the run.

So when I open the report it is empty.

I have tried lowering the cucumber version to see if there are compatibililty issues, but that did not help.

Comment: Answered in this link: https://github.com/orgs/allure-framework/discussions/2221